# Unable to export query result to a file from Sitecore Powershell scirpt with Out-Download command

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

I have a simple powershell script which uses Out-Download command to export the query result to .xlsx file. However, it doesn't seem working. The same scenario as well if I used the download button from Show-ListView window.

Here is the script

```
Import-Function -Name ConvertTo-Xlsx
[byte[]]$outobject = Get-ChildItem master:\ |
    Select-Object -Property Name, ProviderPath, Language, Varsion |
    ConvertTo-Xlsx
Out-Download -Name "report-$datetime.xlsx" -InputObject $outobject
```

As for my initial investigation, I have noticed that one of the request e.g. https://domain.com/-/script/handle/0D81FB63A4524895A114FFF5C2B4299B is being returned 302 response that leads to 404 page.

Versions used:
Sitecore 9.3
Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.0
Sitecore Experience Accelerator 9.3.0.2589

Please let me know if you need more information.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the issue in reference to the posts below. Basically for `Powershell Extension version 6`, you have to enable a config for Identity Server in CM environment. The path should be `\App_Config\Include\Spe\Spe.IdentityServer.config`

[Out-Download access denied to user anonymous](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20935/out-download-access-denied-to-user-anonymous)

[Issue elevating SPE Console in 9.1 Azure PaaS](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/issue-elevating-spe-console-in-9-1-azure-paas)