# SPE reports - CSV download doesn't work

Tags: powershell-extensions, reporting

We have built a powershell report which is working great. However none of the download buttons work.  There is no error in browser nor sitecore logs. it just doesn't download the file. I've tried in Chrome and Edge but no lock.

I've recorded a video as reference.
https://www.screencast.com/t/T4zc0IbrKyrQ

Comment: Did you enable the various features via config. These are disabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Sitecore 9.1+ with SPE 6.3, there's a config file named: `SPE.IdentityServer.config.disabled` that needs to be enabled when using Identity Server.

Related (almost duplicate) questions:

- [Issue elevating SPE Console in 9.1 Azure PaaS](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/issue-elevating-spe-console-in-9-1-azure-paas/28255#28255)
- [Unable to export query result to a file from Sitecore Powershell scirpt with Out-Download command](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25975/unable-to-export-query-result-to-a-file-from-sitecore-powershell-scirpt-with-out/25976#25976)

Comment: Thanks so much Chet! enabling SPE.IdentityServer.config resolved the issue.