# Azure AD login triggered for powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, azure-ad

We are working in Sitecore 9.3.
In the CM instance, we have configured a site as well for internal business users.
The site uses Azure AD B2C for login using WsFederation.
We are able to login to sitecore using Identity server and site login also works fine.

We have a powershell script in sitecore which is triggered using the release pipeline to publish items from the master database to web database.
Its url is -  `https://hostname/-/script/v2/master/Publish-All?user=publisher&password=pswd`

The issue is that this url is redirecting to Azure AD login. How to prevent it from doing so? For this hostname we have not configured Azure AD Login.

Can anybody please help me with the resolution?

Comment: SPE does not natively support Azure AD or Identity Server. There is likely a configuration change you can make to exclude this URL from the authentication requirement.

Comment: @MichaelWest Thanks for comment. Could you please suggest the configuration change we can try?

Comment: Could be related to this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/18775/95